# Scaling text size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I use following script to determine text size of different labels:

```
CASE
WHEN "KKOD" IN (1) THEN 8
WHEN "KKOD" IN (2) THEN 9
-- etc...(here come more lines of similar code)

ELSE 0

END
```

Everything works fine. But now I want to scale all attributes to for example 150%. Is there any simple way to do it?
Is it possible to put attributes in some variable and then multiply it by 1.5 (150%)? Something like this:

```
"KKOD" * 1.5
```

I don't want to change all numbers manually because it will be difficult to change them to something else in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand you are computing the size of the label using an expression. You can then just multiply this result, in the same expression:

[image]

```
1.5 * (
CASE
WHEN "KKOD" IN (2) THEN 8
WHEN "KKOD" IN (3) THEN 9
-- etc...(here come more lines of similar code)

ELSE 0

END
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as you say.

Using the field calculator you can do this.

Attributes before:

[image]

Field calculator highlighted.

Then the field calculator:

[image]

You can also choose to update the existing attribute.

Output:

[image]